# Написать функцию которая находит полусовершенные числа до введенного лимита

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Вообще не знаю, как реализовать, помогите, пожлста.

Answer (score 1):

Полусовершенное число — натуральное число, сумма всех или некоторых собственных делителей которого совпадает с самим этим числом.

```
import math

def devis(n):
    # список для записи делителей
    res = []
    for i in range(1, round(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        if n%i == 0:
            res.append(i)
            # не допускам повторов делителей
            if i*i != n:
                res.append(n//i)
    res.sort()
    return res

# Список первых нескольких полусовершенных чисел:
for num in range(2, 300):
    aa = devis(num)
    s = num
    for i in aa[-2::-1]:
        if s-i>0:
            s = s - i
        elif s-i==0:
            print(num, sep=' ', end=', ')
            break
```

6, 12, 18, 20, 24, 28, 30, 36, 40, 42, 48, 54, 56, 60, 66, 72, 78, 80, 84, 88, 90, 96, 100, 102, 104, 108, 112, 114, 120, 126, 132, 138, 140, 144, 150, 156, 160, 162, 168, 174, 176, 180, 186, 192, 196, 198, 200, 204, 208, 210, 216, 220, 222, 224, 228, 234, 240, 246, 252, 258, 260, 264, 270, 272, 276, 280, 282, 288, 294,

Comment: Не подскажете - жадный метод поиска набора с нужной суммой всегда работает для случая, когда элементы набора - делители суммы?